# Python: Applying a function (mean) to the largest n values in each grouped set of values within a specific column?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I apply a function (mean) to the ***largest n values*** in each grouped set of values within a *specific column*?

```
barB=boxplotyearrating.groupby('rating').gross.nlargest(9)
barB.apply(mean('gross'))
barB.plot.bar()
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? What is your desired output? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why would you `apply` the mean when it's already a method?

Comment: My apologies, I was extremely unclear above. I will repost my question and try my best to adhere to the guidelines advised by @PMende above. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.